# Proper Interop Cleanup

Tags: c#, .net, interop, ms-word

I have the below method for spellchecking in my in house app.  As a new programmer this was pieced together through multiple sources and tweaked until it worked for me.

As I grow and learn I come across things that make me go, hmm.  Like this SO post,[How to properly clean up Excel interop objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c), that talks about proper Interop cleanup.

I noticed it mentions repeatedly the use of `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject()` or `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`.

My question is this, based on the code below do I need this as well?  Thanks

```
        public string CheckSpelling(string text)
    {
        Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
        object nullobj = Missing.Value;
        object template = Missing.Value;
        object newTemplate = Missing.Value;
        object documentType = Missing.Value;
        object visible = false;
        object optional = Missing.Value;
        object savechanges = false;
        app.ShowMe();

        Word._Document doc = app.Documents.Add(ref template, ref newTemplate, ref documentType, ref visible);

        doc.Words.First.InsertBefore(text);
        Word.ProofreadingErrors errors = doc.SpellingErrors;

        var ecount = errors.Count;
        doc.CheckSpelling(ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, 
            ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, 
            ref optional, ref optional, ref optional);
        object first = 0;
        object last = doc.Characters.Count - 1;
        var results = doc.Range(ref first, ref last).Text;
        doc.Close(ref savechanges, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
        app.Quit(ref savechanges, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);

        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say definitely.  You should always use Marshal.ReleaseComObject to clean up unmanaged COM references in .NET code.

Comment: So I would be looking at adding these 3 lines? `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(errors);`

Comment: Yes, I would say that should take care of it.  You'll want to make sure you wrap the existing code in a try...finally block and release the COM objects in the finally block to ensure they actually do get cleaned up.

Comment: Thanks!  Last clarification, and I will look into it myself as well, do I not need `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject()` as well?  I am unsure how that differs is al.

Comment: According to the documentation `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject()` is the same as invoking `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()` in a loop until it returns 0 indicating it was released successfully.  Thus it's safer and better practice to use `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject()`.

Answer (score 1):

You also should explicitly create and release intermediate objects. In the case of `Word._Document doc = app.Documents.Add(...);`, you are implicitly creating a _Documents object that needs to be released. You should break it into two lines:

```
Word._Documents docs = app.Documents;
Word._Document doc = docs.Add(...);
// release docs and doc after use
```

It's often called the *two dots rule*. Anytime that there are two dots in COM interop code, you probably need to break it out, so the same rule would apply to `doc.Words.First.InsertBefore(text);` line.